# How to associate hardware volume control to USB speakers?

Tags: 10.10, sound, usb, xubuntu

My Xubuntu system recognizes my speakers, and I can change the mixer settings to make them the active sound device, but no matter what I do, the hardware dial will only affect the onboard sound device.

`generic-usb 0003:046D:0A19.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [            Logitech              Logitech Z205  ] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input2`

updated to reflect the fact that this was Xubuntu desktop (from Kubuntu install originally) where I had this problem. I was able to easily do this from Ubuntu Natty installation.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory google search reveals the Ubuntu team has been working quite a bit on its USB speaker support. It's quite likely this is a 10.10 bug, fixed in Natty. I haven't found your specific bug yet, but if I do I'll come back here and add it to my answer.